# How can I reduce the repainting area to use "background-attachment: fixed;" on Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: html, css

If I use `background-attachment: fixed;` on `<body>` element,
it would be good.
When the page is scrolled, repainting only scroll bar.

[demo1 (no repainting)](https://jsfiddle.net/akiho/ceg5tv7o/)

but, If I use `background-attachment: fixed;` on some element like `<div>`, it would be heavy page.
repainting all of the area.

[demo2 (repainting all)](https://jsfiddle.net/akiho/w51r0mm1/)

It would be nice if we could do small area repainting on the demo2 situation.

Comment: Actually I don't understand what you want exactly, what is "small area" you want?

Comment: I think it is because div is scrolling and different part of image is showed (guess chrome deletes not visible parts of image to reduce memory usage). You may also look here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/ for clarification.

Comment: I mean ... open the Chrome Developer Tools. [ > Rendering > show paint rectangles ] , and watch the demo1 and demo2 with scrolling. then we can watch repainting area.

Comment: Thanks for comment. At the demo2 the box class changes height: 1000px, we can keep watching repainting now during the scrolling, in spite of all of the view has no image.